# Does Dagger support multibinding with KClass<*> type?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-reflect

I have a KeyMap like this:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@MapKey
annotation class JsonSerializerKey(val value: KClass<*>)
```

and want to provide them as:

```
// #1 doesn't work
Map<KClass<*>, @JvmSuppressWildcards KSerializer<*>>


// #2 works
Map<Class<*>, @JvmSuppressWildcards KSerializer<*>>
```

Dagger can't find and collect provided items when requesting `KClass` (with below error) but it works with `Class`.

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<?>,kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer<?>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

How can I achieve map of `KClass` in dagger multibinding?

P.S: All provided `JsonSerializerKey` items are written in Kotlin.